# How to select a data point using Power BI Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am looking for a way to change the current data selection of a Power BI report programmatically using the Javascript API. I have seen that custom visuals can use SelectionManager to select data points. Is it possible to take a similar approach to change the selection in an embedded report?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the details of selected data points but will not be able to change the selection in an embedded report using Javascript API. To get the details of selection, find the below code snippet:

```js
report.on("dataSelected", function (event) {
    let data = event.detail;
    console.log("Event - dataSelected:\n", data.dataPoints);
});
```

Output-
[image]

Please find the reference here for data selection event and other events:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/handle-events